# Cflags in Makefile not appearing

Tags: c, makefile

I have a makefile, but it seems like the cflags are only working for certain files in my program, and I am not sure why.

Here is what happens when I use make:

```
$ make
gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -g -c main.c
gcc  -c fw.c
gcc  -c trie.c
gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -g -c linked.c
gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -g -o fw main.o fw.o trie.o linked.o
```

You can see that when trying to make fw.c and trie.c it doesn't include the flags, but it does include the flags for the other files.

Here is my makefile:

```
 CC = gcc
 CFLAGS = -Wall -ansi -pedantic -g
 MAIN = main
 OBJS = main.o fw.o trie.o linked.o
 all : $(MAIN)

 $(MAIN) : $(OBJS) fw.h trie.h linked.h
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o fw $(OBJS)

 main.o : main.c fw.h trie.h linked.h
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c main.c

 fw.o : fw.c fw.h trie.h
     $(CC) $(CGLAGS) -c fw.c

 trie.o : trie.c fw.h trie.h linked.h
     $(CC) $(CGLAGS) -c trie.c

 linked.o : linked.c trie.h linked.h
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c linked.c

 rm :
     rm *.o $(MAIN) core
```

I also have an additional problem in that whenever I use make with unchanged files from the last make, it still executes this line:

```
$ make
gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -g -o fw main.o fw.o trie.o linked.o
```

Whereas usually, it gives me the message "nothing to be done for all". I have tried to compare this makefile to my other working makefiles, but I can't find the error(s). Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: You can fix the second issue by creating output with the appropriate name (your rule looks for a output `main` but you're generating `fw`).

Comment: @StephenNewell Does this mean I can't make the name of the executable fw? Because I think I need the MAIN variable to be equal to main since that is where my main function is.

Comment: The only thing you use `MAIN` for is the name of the executable. It has nothing to do with where your `main` function is. So you can safely change it to `MAIN = fw`. But you may want to change `MAIN` to something more meaningful, like `EXEFILE` or `PROGRAM`.

Comment: @user3386109 Oh ok, that makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Since the linker command doesn't create `main` as a file, every time you  run `make`, it runs the commands that you've told it will create `main`, but when you rerun it, it still finds that `main` has not been created.  Use `MAIN = fw` to get the result you wanted/expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have typos in your `Makefile`:

```
 fw.o : fw.c fw.h trie.h
     $(CC) $(CGLAGS) -c fw.c

 trie.o : trie.c fw.h trie.h linked.h
     $(CC) $(CGLAGS) -c trie.c
```

Note the `G`.  Instead, use this:

```
 fw.o : fw.c fw.h trie.h
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c fw.c

 trie.o : trie.c fw.h trie.h linked.h
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c trie.c
```

Comment: Trivial typos should just be closed as off-topic with a comment, not given full-blown answers like this.

Comment: @Barmar I'm the only one who vote to close the question... answer to close question don't hurt, you should follow your own advice and vote to close the question with me !